# Notification to ViewModel of model completion?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a fileupload utility in javascript/knockout. In my viewmodel i'm calling a function on the model `.upload()` that are async xhr type requests. What i want to know in the viewModel is when all xhr requests are finished:

```
this.upload = function () {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.files().length; i++) {
        self.files()[i].upload();
    }

    this.uploadComplete(true);
};
```

`this.uploadComplete(true);` of course does not work since the calls are async. What is the correct way to communicate from the model back to the viewmodel that the upload is complete (note there can be multiple files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files' `upload` method *should* return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (or something like it). You can collect them in an array, and then

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function () {
    self.uploadComplete(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. Never had the opportunity to use promises yet (though i heard the term plenty of times). Worked like a charm. Because we already had a dependency on jquery i decided to use jquery promises.